# Ansible win_service stop fails - How to assert?

Tags: ansible

I do a simple service stop in ansible for a windows service:

```
- name: stop service
  win_service:
    name: "{{ tomcat_srv_name }}"
    state: stopped
```

Due to a problem on the remote server, the stop fails. In case I try this on the remote server i get a timeout. but the above ansible statement hangs forever. 
Is there a way to catch this? Something like wait_for ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on @kfreezy's note I have build this block to catch a potential error and react accordingly:

```
  block:
    # try to stop the service
    - win_service:
        name: "{{ srv_name }}"
        state: stopped
      async: 45
      poll: 5
      register: service_stop_info
    - debug:
        msg: "STOP seevice {{ srv_name }} results in: {{ service_stop_info.state }}"
  rescue:
    # in case the service can not be stopped, kill its process 
    - name: Kill process of service
      win_command: taskkill /f /fi "Services eq {{ srv_name }}"
      register: cmd_result_service_kill
    - debug: 
        msg: "KILL process of service {{ srv_name }} results in: {{ cmd_result_service_kill.stdout }}"  
  always:
    # restart the service 
    - win_service:
        name: "{{ srv_name }}"
        state: started 
      register: service_start_info
    - debug:
        msg: "START service {{ srv_name }} results in: {{ service_start_info.state }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

[Async and polling](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/wait_for_module.html) should work (haven't used it on a windows machine). You'll probably want to tweak the values a bit depending on how long it normally takes to stop tomcat.

```
- name: stop service
  win_service:
    name: "{{ tomcat_srv_name }}"
    state: stopped
  async: 45
  poll: 5
```